# How Do I Correctly Nest Quotations in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use

```
    $var = "
        <?php
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
                $reply = $_POST['reply'];
                $query = 'insert into reply (threadId,reply) values (' . $GLOBALS["id"] . ',' . $reply . ')';
            }
        ?>
    "
```

it throws out "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)"
What should I do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to place code in a variable? please be more verbose

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: Yes I want to place the code in a variable and I want to execute the code in it later inside of the initial variable

Comment: What you should do is rethinking the whole approach. It doesn't make sense. And certainly isn't advisable at this level of experience.

Comment: How else am I supposed to write it to a file?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ -- else: heredoc or nowdoc. and certainly: parameter binding.